# Installed Java 8 has nonsense characters for Start Menu shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, java, start-menu

I can't believe how I cannot find the same question already online. After I installed Java 8 from https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp, the Windows shortcuts are comprised of completely gibberish characters:

»ñÈ¡°ïÖú, ·ÃÎÊ Java.com, ¼ì²é¸üÐÂ, ¹ØÓÚ Java, and ÅäÖÃ Java.

is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: Uninstall, reboot, reinstall :: this time, check the Installation Settings, & ensure you select correct local language

Comment: Uninstall ALL Java versions (Java does not always do that automatically); restart the computer, download the FULL version (not stub) and install that and check.